# ngFor - Unable to sort array of objects Angular 5

Tags: angular, arrayobject, arrayofarrays

I have array of array of objects in Angular and I'm trying to sort into HTML.

The output of array is show in chrome console :

[image]

With sample inside the array :

[image]

in typescript file:

```js
this.results = [
  [{score: 0.535632, tone_id: "anger", tone_name: "Colère"}],
  [{score: 0.633569, tone_id: "anger", tone_name: "Colère"},
   {score: 0.506763, tone_id: "analytical", tone_name: "Analytique"}],
  [{score: 0.895438, tone_id: "joy", tone_name: "Joie"}],
  [{score: 0.736445, tone_id: "joy", tone_name: "Joie"},
   {score: 0.955445, tone_id: "analytical", tone_name: "Analytique"}],
  [{score: 0.796404, tone_id: "anger", tone_name: "Colère"}],
  [{score: 0.52567, tone_id: "sadness", tone_name: "Tristesse"},
   {score: 0.639934, tone_id: "anger", tone_name: "Colère"}],
  [{score: 0.557769, tone_id: "fear", tone_name: "Peur"}],
  [{score: 0.51583, tone_id: "joy", tone_name: "Joie"},
  {score: 0.874372, tone_id: "confident", tone_name: "Confiant"}]    
];
```

In the html file, I'm looping the array initialized as `results` using `*ngFor` but can't display objects inside array:

```html
<tbody *ngIf="results.length">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let res of results;let i = index">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Score: {{res.score}}</td>
            <td>Emotion: {{res.tone_name}}</td> 
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
<tbody>
```

It shows empty result in table on the browser.

Comment: You don't have an array of objects. You have an array or arrays. So `res` is an array, not an object.

Comment: I got it, I don't understand why it return an error referring to *ngFor can't iterate objects ? In the console : ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Probably because of code that you're not showing us. Post a complete minimal example as a StackBlitz.

Comment: It works fine on StackBlitz: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyu9wo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) But on my browser it remain empty table with the same error. What should I do ?

Comment: Find out what the difference is between the stackblitz example and your actual code.

Comment: Actually @JB Nizet, I have another array to loop and found out lately that I can't loop two array for one *ngFor. So I'm trying to figure out to solve this. The whole code is always on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyu9wo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Answer (score 0):

With `*ngFor="let res of results"`, `res` is going to be whatever is at each index in `results`. In each case it's going to be another array, so you'll need another `*ngFor` to go through its contents.

```html
<tbody *ngIf="results.length">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let res of results;let i = index">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <table>
          <tr *ngFor="let obj of res">
            <td>Score: {{obj.score}}</td>
            <td>Emotion: {{obj.tone_name}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
<tbody>
```

Comment: It doesn't show anything in the table with error in the console: ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.